# How to update Doc2Vec model with new sentences?

Tags: python

I use Wikipedia for Doc2Vec model training. There is not enough memory to train the model in one go. Because, when I try to build the vocabulary with all sentences, my python breaks.

So, I would like to split this process into pieces. 
I select few documents, train the model, save the model, open old model and try to update it with new sentences\labels.

My code for the first training

```py
model = gensim.models.Doc2Vec(min_count=5, window=10, size=300, sample=1e-3, negative=5, workers=3)

model.build_vocab(sentences.to_array())

sentences_list=sentences.to_array() 
Idx=range(len(sentences_list))

for epoch in range(10):
    random.shuffle(Idx)
    perm_sentences = [sentences_list[i] for i in Idx]
    model.train(perm_sentences)

model.save('example')
```

This code works perfect. 
After that I do

```py
model = Doc2Vec.load('example')

sentences_list_new=sentences_new.to_array() 
Idx=range(len(sentences_list_new))

for epoch in range(10):
    random.shuffle(Idx)
    perm_sentences_new = [sentences_list_new[i] for i in Idx]
    model.train(perm_sentences_new)
```

But I get Warning:

```
WARNING:gensim.models.word2vec:supplied example count (9999) did not equal expected count (133662)
```

And new words are not added to model.

Then I try to build vocabulary with new words:

```py
model.build_vocab(sentences_list_new)
```

But have this error:

```
RuntimeError: must sort before initializing vectors/weights
```

BUT... after this new words are in vocabulary.

Where is the problem?

Comment: Not sure what's wrong, but (1) Just off my head, I recall Doc2Vec having some kind of labeled sentences as doc-level, and the two levels, sentences and vocabs, are trained either at the same time or just one of them. I don't see you dealing with sentences (2) There is a function `model.sort_vocab()` for the Doc2Vec object. Not sure if that solves it.

Comment: This also does not work. Look at the comment below.

Answer (score 1):

From Gordon Mohr's answer [here](http://gensim.narkive.com/UQfxyhec/gensim-6028-model-build-vocab-throws-runtimeerror):

> Currently, the model discovers the vocab only once so using
>   `build_vocab()` is not supported again.

according to [sebastien-j](https://github.com/sebastien-j) in [this discussion](https://github.com/piskvorky/gensim/issues/293):

> the memory usage should be approximately 8 * size * |V| bytes (plus
>   some overhead).
>
> For |V|=10^7 and size=500, this is 40 GB.
>
> See if your system has enough memory  (if it does there could be a
>   python version issue which is unlikely in your case...)
>
> If it doesn't you could try increasing the `min_count`